# Python: PCA issue with data analysis

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, ascii, pca

I am attempting to do some data analysis with PCA sklearn package. The issue I'm currently running into is the way my code is analysing the data.

An example of some of the data is as follows

wavelength                intensity
;        [um]                 [W/m**2/um/sr]
   196.078431372549       1.108370393265022E-003
   192.307692307692       1.163428008597600E-003
   188.679245283019       1.223639983609668E-003

The code written so far is as follows:

```
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=True, with_std=True) #scales the data

data_crescent=ascii.read('earth_crescent.dat',data_start=4958, data_end=13300, delimiter=' ')#where the data is being read


#where each variable comes from in the dat 
y_intensity_crescent=data_crescent['col2'][:]
x_wave_crescent=data_crescent['col1'][:]

standard_y_crescent=StandardScaler().fit_transform(y_intensity_crescent)#standardizing the intensity variable

#PCA runthrough of data 
pca= PCA(n_components=2)
principalCrescentY=pca.fit_transform(standard_y_crescent)
principalDfcrescent = pd.DataFrame(data = principalCrescentY
             , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])



finalDfcrescent = pd.concat([principalDfcrescent, [y_intensity_crescent]], axis = 1)
```

Once ran, the data produces this error:

```
    ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample
```

In order to analyze the data via PCA, the data needs to be transformed into a 2D model, to produce the expected results. Any work around would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving one feature `y_intensity_crescent` to your pca object by doing: `principalCrescentY=pca.fit_transform(standard_y_crescent)`. You are in fact giving only one dimension to your pca algorithm. Roughly: principal component analysis takes multiple features time series and will combine them into components which are combination of the features. If you want 2 components you need more than 1 features.

Here is some example of how to use it properly: [PCA tutorial using sklearn](https://towardsdatascience.com/pca-using-python-scikit-learn-e653f8989e60)

Comment: You are right. X is only a vector. It does not make sense to take 2 components since there is not even 2 features. Be aware that the error that you get is due to the shape of `X`. It should be 2D array and therefore, you should do `X.reshape(-1, 1)` to get a single feature array. But you will still have the issue mentioned before. Note that you should use a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` to connect the standardization and PCA: `transformer = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), PCA()); transformer.fit_transform(X)`

Comment: Yep that was it. Additionally, the data didn't necessarily need to be standardized. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @domryan glad it helped! Don't forget to accept the answer for the other users